# link to a page with user's selection from dropdown, selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that has many dropdown lists, I wish to have a feature that when the user selects something he can send a link of the page with the option he selected.

Therefore I tried to use `pushState` - it changes the URL, which is great, but when I refresh it actually says that the page doesn't exist.

```
function ChangeUrl(title, url) {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Title: title, Url: url };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    } else {
        alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
}
```

Comment: you could use .htaccess if web server is Apache to redirect all requests to index file

Comment: nope i'm not using apache at all, and by the way, the value i'm having in the url is the ID of the user's selection

Comment: Well how you want to get to the page if you haven't created it? Its like I want to drive a car but i don't have it

Comment: @YaraBinSaif so what's your webserver ?

Comment: @Farhad i'm currently working on this locally

Comment: @StupidKid i get what u mean, but there are 100+ options, do i need to create a page for each one?

Comment: @YaraBinSaif local or server in both you should use web server ! 
what's your URL in browser ??
you need a dynamic route and for this you SHOULD redirect all your request to index file

Comment: @Farhad oh, i'm using IIS. the url is like: localhost:portnumber

Comment: so in IIS you should  redirect all requests to your main file in this case if in browser url is /user/120 or /user/66523 you can get those user id's in your index file however my better suggestion is using JS frameworks such as Vuejs or React , they have their own router and it makes it easy to go on

Comment: @Farhad do you think it would be practical to use #'ID' in the url ? or that would not save the user's selection?

Comment: The alternative to /user/120 would be /user?id=120 or /user#120 - /user/120 looks for the "120" page while the other two look for the "user" page.  If you want /user/120 to point to the user page then you need url redirection using either iis settings as suggested or a proper server tech such as MVC (example only).

Comment: @Farhad then should the onLoad read the url and choose values based on the value there?

Comment: @YaraBinSaif yes , also as I mentioned those frameworks have router and do this for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hash part of your url (anchors).
Simply add your information to the window.location.hash variable.

Below is some Example. But be aware that this code does not work here on stackoverflow.

The code below registers a onChange event to the dropdown. When the dropdown gets changed, the hash of the url gets re-writen.

When the page gets loaded, it checks if there is a hash and if so it selects the ID in the dropdown.

**UPDATE** I edited my answer an changed the code, now you can manage your hash values much easier and you can manage as many hashes as you like. Anchorman is a little helper object to manage all the hashes.

```js
/**
 * anchorman is a helper object for url hashes
 */
let anchorman = (function() {
  "use strict";

  let _hashes = {};

  /**
   * Reads the hash from the address bar of the browser
   */
  let _readHash = function() {
      if (window.location.hash) {
        let hash = window.location.hash;

        // cut of server parameter and keep only the anchors
        let pos = hash.indexOf('?');
        if (pos !== -1) {
          hash = hash.substr(0, pos);
        }

        //cut of leading dash
        if (hash.indexOf('#') === 0) {
          hash = hash.substr(1, hash.length);
        }

        //split the parameters into separate pieces
        let splitHash = hash.split("&");

        //build the parameter list array
        for (let i = 0; i < splitHash.length; i++) {
          let splitParameter = splitHash[i].split("=");
          _hashes[splitParameter[0]] = splitParameter[1];
        }
      }
    },

    /**
     * Initialise it self
     * @private
     */
    _init = function() {
      _readHash();
    },

    /**
     * Checks if a specific hash is set
     *
     * @param key
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    hasHash = function(key) {
      _readHash();
      return _hashes.hasOwnProperty(key);
    },

    /**
     * Returns the wanted hash value
     * @param hashName string
     * @returns {*}
     */
    getHash = function(hashName) {
      if (hasHash(hashName)) {
        return _hashes[hashName];
      }

      return null;
    },


    /**
     * Returns all hash parameters as a string for the use in a address bar
     *
     * @returns {string}
     */
    toString = function() {
      let hashString = "";
      for (let key in _hashes) {
        if (_hashes.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.length > 0) {
          hashString += "&" + key + "=" + _hashes[key];
        }
      }

      return hashString;
    },

    /**
     * Updates the address bar of the browser and also the history, so back navigation is no problem
     */
    _updateAddressBar = function() {
      window.location.hash = toString();
    },

    /**
     * Updates a specific parameter in the hash, if it does not exist it will be created
     *
     * @param {string} key
     * @param {string} value
     */
    setHashValue = function(key, value) {
      _readHash();

      _hashes[key] = value;
      if (_hashes[key] === null || _hashes[key].length <= 0 || typeof(_hashes[key]) === 'undefined') {
        delete _hashes[key];
      }

      _updateAddressBar();
    },

    /**
     * Remove a specific parameter in the hash.
     *
     * @param hashKey
     */
    removeHash = function(hashKey) {
      _readHash();

      if (hasHash(hashKey)) {
        if (_hashes.hasOwnProperty(hashKey)) {
          delete _hashes[hashKey];
        }
      }

      _updateAddressBar();
    },

    /**
     * Checks if any hash is set
     * This is needed because array.length does not work because of (unknown) reasons.
     *
     * If the exceptions array is set, it will check if any hash beside these in the exception array are set.
     *
     * @param exceptions An Array with exceptions to ANY Rule
     *
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    hasAnyHash = function(exceptions) {
      _readHash();

      for (let key in _hashes) {
        if (key.length > 0 && _hashes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if (exceptions !== undefined && exceptions.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            continue;
          }

          return true;
        }
      }

      return false;
    };

  // call the initialisation
  _init();

  // public functions
  return {
    getHash: getHash,
    hasAnyHash: hasAnyHash,
    hasHash: hasHash,
    removeHash: removeHash,
    setHashValue: setHashValue,
    toString: toString,
  };
}());

// register onChange events to the dropdowns
$('.userDropdowns').on('change', function() {
  // when a dropdown changes, write the new value to the url hash
  let dropdownId = $(this).attr('id');
  let selectedElementId = $(this).val();
  anchorman.setHashValue(dropdownId, selectedElementId);
});

// this code will run when the document is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
  // changes the city dropdown selection if the ddCity hash value is set on page load
  let cityId = anchorman.getHash('ddCity');
  if (cityId !== null) {
    $('#ddCity').val(cityId).trigger('change');
  }

  // changes the department dropdown selection if the ddDepartment hash value is set on page load
  let departmentId = anchorman.getHash('ddDepartment');
  if (departmentId !== null) {
    $('#ddDepartment').val(departmentId).trigger('change');
  }

  // changes the section dropdown selection if the ddSection hash value is set on page load
  let sectionId = anchorman.getHash('ddSection');
  if (sectionId !== null) {
    $('#ddSection').val(sectionId).trigger('change');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="ddCity" class="userDropdowns">
    <option value="1">NY</option>
    <option value="2">Paris</option>
    <option value="3">Berlin</option>
    <option value="4">London</option>
</select>

<select id="ddDepartment" class="userDropdowns">
    <option value="1">North</option>
    <option value="2">South</option>
    <option value="3">East</option>
    <option value="4">West</option>
</select>

<select id="ddSection" class="userDropdowns">
    <option value="1">Section 1</option>
    <option value="2">Section 2</option>
    <option value="3">Section 3</option>
    <option value="4">Section 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks, can i use the same thing for three dropdowns? like, the user has to select : 1)City 2)Department 3)Section

Comment: is it possible to split the three and read them in readHash? I tried but idk where to point at the splitting point

Comment: also, the end of my url is like #selectedId=0, i put an alert inside if **(splitHash.length === 2) {**  and it's not entering it! :(

Comment: you are correct, it never enters the If statement. I was a bit in a hurry and will write a new answer (it will be a bit bigger). But then you schould be able to do as many dropdowns as you want. give me just a view minutes...

Comment: I edited my answer, it is a bit complex but I think it does what you need